Does the projection onto invariant subspace commute with one-parameter unitary group
Consider a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$ and a  continuous one-parameter group of unitary transformations $\{U_t \}$ acting on it. Consider also the projection $\mathbb{P}$ onto the subspace of $\mathcal{H}$ that is invariant under the action of the one-parameter group. Is it true that $\mathbb{P}U_t = U_t \mathbb{P}$, for all $t$?
My intuition is that the projection $\mathbb{P}$ is essentially the "average" of all the $U_t$, by von Neumann's mean ergodic theorem $\mathbb{P} = \lim \frac{1}{T} \int U_t$, hence they should commute.
Is this true? Is there an easier way to argue about this?

Suppose we have any unitary representation $G\to U(H)$ of a group $G$ on a Hilbert space, and $V\le H$ is any subrepresentation (closed invariant subspace). Then the orthogonal complement $V^\perp$ is also a subrepresentation (if $w\in V^\perp$ then for any $g\in G$ and $v\in V$ we can check $\langle gw,v\rangle=\langle w,g^{-1}v\rangle=0$ so $gw\in V^\perp$ too). Then for any $h\in H$ we can write $h=v+w$ with $v\in V$ and $w\in V^\perp$, in which case $gP_V(h)=gv$ and $P_V(gh)=P_V(gv+gw)=gv$ too, so we conclude $gP_V(h)=P_V(gh)$.

BTW, you can't say "the subspace that is invariant under the action" because there are infinitely many of those. Maybe you meant "the subspace of invariants" (i.e. fixed points), but that is a very special case of a closed invariant subspace.
